# Where's this coastline in Gros Morne National Park?

Tags: identify-this, newfoundland

From [Newfoundland Labrador Tourism's Instagram:](https://www.instagram.com/p/B0BZ56NJXJC/)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is just south of Trout River. From http://townoftroutriver.com/walking-trails/:

> Across the harbour from the cliff plateau you will see a large rock structure the locals call The Old Man (who was once accompanied by an Old Woman, who has since crumbled).  The trail to see The Old Man/ Lighthouse trail begins on the other side of the Feeder Bridge.  This winding trail leads directly to these neat rock formations, while giving marvelous camera shots of the Town of Trout River, the river itself, fishing boats and mountain range.  You can carry on past the nature made statue along soft fields to view the ocean and cliffs.

[image]